# How to stop JLabel.seticon from constantly repainting on top of everything else

Tags: swing, jlabel

I am trying to keep a `JInternalFrame` called `GUIWindow.SpecialOptionsPopUp` stay on top of a another `JInternalFrame` with a `JLabel` called 'label' in it. The problem occurs when label constantly updates an image within it.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
public class ForumQuestion extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JLabel label;
    private JInternalFrame internalFrame;
    private JInternalFrame internalFrame_1;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ForumQuestion frame = new ForumQuestion();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public ForumQuestion() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        internalFrame_1 = new JInternalFrame("New JInternalFrame");
        internalFrame_1.setBounds(0, 0, 424, 250);
        contentPane.add(internalFrame_1);

        label = new JLabel("");
        internalFrame_1.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        internalFrame_1.setVisible(true);

        internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("New JInternalFrame");
        internalFrame.setBounds(145, 25, 171, 195);
        contentPane.add(internalFrame);
        internalFrame.setVisible(true);

        UpdateImage updateimage = new UpdateImage();
        updateimage.start();


    }

    private class UpdateImage extends Thread{

        public UpdateImage(){

        }
        public void run(){
            while(true){
                label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Ali/EclipseWorkspace/ForumQuestion/testimage.png"));
                internalFrame.repaint();
                contentPane.setComponentZOrder(internalFrame, 0);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Try including a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I have no idea why you would has a while loop. A JInternalFrame should only be added to a JDesktopPane and should not be painted above a label. If you want a popup window, then you should be using a modal JDialog or maybe a JOptionPane.

Comment: Sing is not thread safe, you are violating the single thread rules of swing. Perhaps you'd like to explain why your loading the same image inside a infinite loop inside a thread?

Comment: As MadProgrammer stated, the threading is not done properly. It might not even be necessary.  Also, as camickr stated, why the while loop? And INFINITE on top of that.  I bet that is not necessary either.  This is probably what you want: http://www.coderanch.com/t/333020/GUI/java/Front

Comment: I'm working with OpenCV where I manipulate each frame of a video and display it on a label. The infinite nature of the while loop is solely for example purposes. If threading is bad for swing, the only alternate I can think of is there to be a listener of some sort for the JInternalFrame. Please let me know the way.